# X86_64 Assembly not returning right values when loading from memory address

Tags: memory, assembly, load, x86-64, cpu-registers

I'm new at X86_64 assembly, and I am trying to implement a brk memory management program, but I'm having some issues with some lines of the code.

.data part:

```
.section .data

heap_start: .double 0

.equ HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET, 0
.equ HDR_SIZE_OFFSET,4
.equ UNAVAILABLE, 0
.equ AVAILABLE, 1
```

the text section part with the issue:

```
.text
alloc:
    movq heap_start, %rdx
loop:
    movq HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%rdx), %rcx
    cmpq $UNAVAILABLE, %rcx
    jne found_space
loop2:
    movq HDR_PROX(%rdx), %rdx
    cmpq %rdx, heap_start
    jne loop
    jmp new_brk
found_space:

    cmpq HDR_SIZE_OFFSET(%rdx), %rdi
    jg loop2
```

The problem is, that HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%rdx) should load the contents addressed by 0 on heap_start. However, it is returning a completely different memory address into %rcx.

heap_start points to the start of the memory array I want to check, and the first element is 0.
When I use x/nfu to examine memory on gdb, it shows the following:

```
(gdb) x/nfu $rdx
0x602001:  0
```

but after

```
movq HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%rdx), %rcx
```

the %rcx is:

```
(gdb) print $rcx
$1 = 429496729600
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are using is 32 bits, as shown by the offsets being 4 bytes apart, but you are accessing it as 64 bits. If you were to print 429496729600 in hexadecimal, you would get 0x6400000000, which shows that the low 32 bits are all 0.

To fix this, either change your data fields to be 64 bits wide, or change to 32 bit accesses by changing the `q` suffixes to `l`s and the registers to start with `e` instead of `r` when you are working with data:

```
.text
alloc:
    movq heap_start, %rdx               # Address, 64 bits
loop:
    movl HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%rdx), %ecx   # Data, 32 bits
    cmpl $UNAVAILABLE, %ecx             # Data
    jne found_space
loop2:
    movq HDR_PROX(%rdx), %rdx           # Address
    cmpq %rdx, heap_start               # Address
    jne loop
    jmp new_brk
found_space:
    cmpl HDR_SIZE_OFFSET(%rdx), %edi    # Data
    jg loop2
```